# Derivative of product of n factors

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I want to compute:

$l'(x)$ where $l(x)= \prod_{i=0}^n (x-x_i)$

It holds: $$l'(x)= \sum_{i=0}^n (1-x_i) \prod_{{i=0},{i \ne j}}^n (x-x_j) $$

$$ \overset{!}{=} \prod_{{i=0},{i \ne j}}^n (x_i-x_j)$$

How can I get to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first step is incorrect. By the product rule
$$l'(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\left( \left(\frac{d}{dx}(x-x_i)\right)\prod_{j=0:\,j\neq i}^n (x-x_j)\right)=\sum_{i=0}^n \prod_{j=0:\,j\neq i}^n (x-x_j).$$